# Как скопировать информацию из файла в файл?

Tags: python, файлы

```
impfile = open('путь')
textfile = impfile.read()
print(textfile)
impfilecopy = open('путь', 'w')
impfilecopy.write(textfile)
print(impfilecopy)
```

Почему то не копирует информацию из первого файла во второй.

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно скопировать полностью файл, то можно воспользоваться модулем shutil.

```
import shutil 

shutil.copy2(r'C:\main.txt', r'D:\filename.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [12]: with open('file1.txt') as first, open('file2.txt', 'w') as second:
    ...:     data = first.read()
    ...:     second.write(data)
```

Comment: спасибо, большое! а зачем нужны эти символы In [12]:...:...: ?

Comment: @MaKaroNNiK о том что это Вы можете почитать тут: [ipython](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython)

Comment: словами стоит упомянуть в чём конкретно проблема в вопросе (файл не закрыт, изменения не видны) и как именно ваш ответ её решает (with-конструкция закрывает файлы автоматически).

Answer (score -1):

```
impfile = open('t.txt', 'r')
textfile = impfile.read()
impfile.close()
print(textfile)
impfilecopy = open('a.txt', 'w')
impfilecopy.write(textfile)
impfilecopy.close()
```

Comment: спасибо, но почему то print(f) выдает число 21, а не копию текста первого.

Comment: он выдает кол-во символов добавленные в файл

Answer (score -1):

```
file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
textfile1 = file1.read()
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'w')
file2.write(textfile1)
print(textfile1)
file1.close()
file2.close()
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')
textfile2 = file2.read()
print(textfile2)
file2.close()
```